# Where is page social_django.views.auth?

Tags: django

I'm trying to make auth with google. But get

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/google/
Raised by:  social_django.views.auth
Backend not found
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'social_django',
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '...'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = '...'
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'
```

urls.py(root)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('books.urls')),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
    path('comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),
    path('account/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social'))
]
```

login.html

```
<a href="{% url "social:begin" "google" %}">Login with Google</a>
```

I did migrations for social_django

Comment: did you add all the required auth backends? https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html#authentication-backends

Comment: AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
)

 i have this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using :

```
<a href="{% url "social:begin" "**google**" %}">
  Login with Google
</a>
```

Use:

```
< a href="{% url 'social:begin' '**google-oauth2**' %}?next={{ request.path }}">
  Login with Google
</a>
```

Source : [official documentation](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html#templates)